# how to call pl sql function to apex item?

Tags: oracle, function, oracle-apex

I create  PL/SQL function in oracle database named `TOTAL_DISCOUNT (ORDER_ID NUMBER)` so I want to call this function in apex item page?

Comment: have you exposed this sql function as a web-service ?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! It sounds like you're not in the right place. Your question appears to be about Oracle's DBMS, whereas this site is focused on Salesforce.com, its products, and platforms. The two are not related at all. You may try [dba.se] or [so] instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use it in an item, there are two places you can do that:

- source
- default value

Usage would be just the same:

- type would be (for example) "PL/SQL Function Body"
- the body itself would then be (presuming that the `order_id` is, actually, a page item named `:P1_ORDER_ID`)

  ```
  return TOTAL_DISCOUNT (:P1_ORDER_ID);
  ```